# Optimize query: Select in Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization

Lets say i have a table to store the blogs (table name is blogs) of each user.
But also have a table to store the blogs from other users that the user liked (table name is likedBlogs), yes?

so to retrieve them i just do:
-Select user's blogs.
-Add the blogs he liked.

```
    $q = mysql_query("
SELECT id 
FROM blogs 
WHERE (iduser = $id) 
      OR id IN 
       (SELECT idblog 
        FROM likedBlogs 
        WHERE iduser='$id') 
      AND (id > 0) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 20
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Can i do this better? (how would you qualify in performance this query?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can better refactor it usign EXISTS instead of IN.

`IN` requires the entire result set be returned and then begin search for a value, but `EXISTS` check row by row and interrupt inner query when first occurence is found.

```
SELECT id  
FROM blogs  
WHERE (iduser = $id)        
OR EXISTS
      (SELECT idblog         
       FROM likedBlogs          
       WHERE iduser='$id' AND idblog = id)
AND (id > 0)  
ORDER BY id 
DESC  LIMIT 20
```

See [Optimizing IN/=ANY Subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/in-subquery-optimization.html)

> very useful optimization is to “inform” the subquery that the only
>   rows of interest are those where the inner expression inner_expr is
>   equal to outer_expr. This is done by pushing down an appropriate
>   equality into the subquery's WHERE clause. That is, the comparison is
>   converted to this:  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE subquery_where AND
>   outer_expr=inner_expr)

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet : yep, significantly on large data sets. See link I've provided, I believe you can search intrawebs for `EXISTS vs IN MySql` and you'll find a lot of reviews

Comment: In SQL Server 2005+ `EXISTS` and `IN` evaluate the same, thankfully.

Comment: @JNK : wow, good to know, thanks! Just tried to look into MSDN regardign IN and not found anything regarding this, you mean that the same execution plan would be generated?

Comment: @sll - yes, and typically it's faster than a `JOIN` since it short circuits.  I use `IN` for evaluation of a single field and `EXISTS` for comparison on multiple fields.

Comment: Interesting! so @JNK, would you recomend any change in this query?

Comment: For MySQL I think this is about as good as it will  get, but I'm not an expert in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would use `join` instead of nested `select`'s.

```
select blogs.id
from blogs inner join likedBlogs on (blogs.iduser = likedBlogs.iduser and blogs.id  = likedBlogs.idblog)
where blogs.iduser = $id
and blogs.id > 0
order by blogs.id desc limit 20
```

**upd** first time I didn't read task statement correctly

```
select blogs.id 
from blogs left join likedBlogs on (blogs.id = likedBlogs.idblog)
where blogs.iduser = $id or likedBlogs.iduser = $id;
```

Comment: thanks, faster than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902611/optimize-query-select-in-select/7902656#7902656 ?

Comment: Is INNER JOIN would be valid for cases when no entries in likedBlogs?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. `left join` is what we need in this case. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine to me. For performance you should make sure you have indexes on the id columns in your database tables.

Comment: uf, i am not using indexes yet... i haven't found anything easy to understand yet..

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better served by a union

```
SELECT id 
FROM blogs 
WHERE iduser = $id AND id > 0
UNION 
SELECT idblog AS id 
FROM likedBlogs 
WHERE iduser='$id' AND idblog > 0
```